# Rx on WinRT: Iterate collection over time

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, system.reactive

I want to iterate a collection by moving from element to element during specific time intervals. So for example this method works fine:

```
        var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4}.ToObservable();
        var b = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        var c = a.Zip(b, (l, r) => l);
        c.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

But I would like to use the value of each element in the list as the interval, so I am using this code:

```
        var a = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4}.ToObservable();
        var b = a.Delay(x => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x)));
        b.Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

As it stated here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx "the new overloads to Delay allow one to specify (optionally) the delay for the subscription as well as the delay for each element based on a selector function". But running the code does not work like expected. It just spits out the elements of the list using 1 sec interval. Like so:

...(1 sec)
1
...(1 sec)
2
...(1 sec)
3
...(1 sec)
4

Instead of

...(1 sec)
1
...(2 sec)
2
...(3 sec)
3
...(4 sec)
4

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
new[] {1,2,3,4,5,}.ToObservable()
    .Select(x => Observable.Return(x).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x)))
    .Concat();
```

Right? You want to use the number as both the value as well as the amount of time to delay?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that advances the iterator on the enumerable source only one step before it waits again (works with infinite enumerable source sequences):

```
static IObservable<T> ToObservableDelay<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> source, 
    Func<T, TimeSpan> delaySelector, 
    IScheduler scheduler
)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(o =>
        scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async (s, c) =>
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var x in source)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(delaySelector(x), c);
                    o.OnNext(x);
                }
                o.OnCompleted();
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException) { /* ignore */ }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                o.OnError(e);
            }
         })
    );
}
```

And here a little demo with an infinite generator:

```
static IEnumerable<double> Uniform(Random rng)
{
    while (true)
        yield return rng.NextDouble();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var source = Uniform(new Random());

    Console.WriteLine("press any key to quit");
    using (var subscription = 
        ToObservableDelay(source, TimeSpan.FromSeconds, Scheduler.Default)
        .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Simple demo code that runs in a RT app:

```
 var source = Uniform(new Random());
 ToObservableDelay(source, TimeSpan.FromSeconds, Scheduler.Default)
     .Take(10)
     .Subscribe(x => Debug.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: Your solution works (had to do a modification in the demo) but I chose the other answer as accepted due to it's simplicity and elegance.

Comment: @Manos: ok, but you see the problem when you try the other solution with the Uniform() infinite generator, don't you? You will quickly run out of memory... In general I think you have to be very careful when using the interactive<->reactive bridge methods.

Comment: Yeap, but in my case I have a finite set of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while trying to solve the same issue. My solution was to use Observable.Generator together with the IEnumerable's enumerator, like so:

```
public static IObservable<T> ToObservable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, TimeSpan time)
{
    var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

    var observable = Observable.Generate(
        enumerator.Current,
        _ => enumerator.MoveNext(),
        _ => enumerator.Current,
        _ => enumerator.Current,
        _ => time);

    return observable;
}
```

This extension method is then simply called like this:

```
var observable = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    .ToObservable(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

using (observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press the Any key to abort");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```